# PHP - Read specific strings/values from stdclass object

Tags: php, string

I would like to read values from a stdclass and show them as strings. A var_dump produces this:

```
object(stdClass)#886 (7) {
["Address"]=>
object(stdClass)#885 (8) {
["AddressLine"]=>
string(0) “”
["AdminDistrict"]=>
string(5) “Wales”
["CountryRegion"]=>
string(14) “United Kingdom”
["District"]=>
string(0) “”
["FormattedAddress"]=>
string(43) “Llangefni, Isle of Anglesey, United Kingdom”
["Locality"]=>
string(9) “Llangefni”
["PostalCode"]=>
string(0) “”
["PostalTown"]=>
string(0) “”
}
["BestView"]=>
object(stdClass)#839 (2) {
["Northeast"]=>
object(stdClass)#881 (3) {
["Altitude"]=>
float(0)
["Latitude"]=>
float(53.261619567871)
["Longitude"]=>
float(-4.3000702857971)
}
```

How to get "Latitude" and show it as string?
Thanks!

Comment: $obj->Address->AddressLine->Latitude, or something like that. Since you've not properly indented that dump, it's hard to tell, but all you have to do is follow the "tree" down to wherever latitude is in the object.

Answer (score 0):

by doing

```
$yourObj->BestView->Northeast->Latitude
```